# Minimum value on most recent date per account MS ACCESS SQL

Tags: ms-access, greatest-n-per-group

I have a MS ACCESS DB table `Riskscore` with the three fields: `CHACCTBS`, `CHRQDATE`, `CHSCORE` and want to find the lowest `CHSCORE` on the most recent `CHRQDATE` per `CHACCTBS` where it is possible to have multiple `CHSCORE` values on the same `CHRQDATE`.  There should be one record returned for each CHACCTBS.  There are about 17,000 records.  Once the query has run, there should be 7008 records returned.

```
CHACCTBS, CHRQDATE, CHSCORE
101    1/1/2014    781
101    1/1/2014    791
101    12/31/2013   717
221    10/01/2013   512
235    1/2/2014     685
235    10/31/2013   600
```

The query should return:

```
101    1/1/2014    781
221    10/01/2013   512
235    1/2/2014     685
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

This would be a good place to use window functions if your RDBMS supports them. The example below is T-SQL so if you are not on SQL Server you may have to adapt the syntax and/or keywords.

Window Functions are ANSI Standard starting with [SQL:2003](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL:2003), and as such you likely have access to them with any modern RDBMS. If you are on SQL Server read about their implementation of `Window Functions` [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx).

```
SELECT CHACCTBS, CHRQDATE, CHSCORE
FROM
(
    SELECT
         MIN(CHSCORE) OVER(PARTITION BY CHACCTBS) As CHACCTBS
        ,CHRQDATE
        ,CHSCORE
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CHACCTBS ORDER BY CHRQDATE DESC, CHSCORE) As Limiter
    FROM RiskScore
) X
WHERE Limiter = 1
```

The subquery returns your `MIN` and other columns, and creates a filter by assigning row numbers by your partition and ordered by descending dates. You then take the first row of each partition in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: They probably want `OVER (... ORDER BY CHRQDATE DESC, CHSCORE)` but good answer.

Comment: The example is actually standard SQL - no T-SQL specialties in there. It will run without any change on Oracle, Postgres and DB2

Comment: Actually this will not compile in SQL Server, unless you specify an alias for the subselect.

Comment: Un fortunately, this is MS Access SQL and the query suggested above results in the following error:  Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'MIN(CHSCORE) OVER(PARTITION BY CHACCTBS)'.

Comment: Made suggested fixes even though it won't work for original question based on updated platform.

Answer (score 2):

```
select
     RiskScore.CHACCTBS
    ,RiskScore.CHRQDATE
    ,Min(RiskScore.CHSCORE) as CHSCORE
from RiskScore
inner join (
    select
         RiskScore.CHACCTBS
        ,Max(RiskScore.CHRQDATE) as CHRQDATE
    from RiskScore
    group by RiskScore.CHACCTBS
    ) as t
    on (RiskScore.CHACCTBS = t.CHACCTBS)
    and (RiskScore.CHRQDATE = t.CHRQDATE)
group by RiskScore.CHACCTBS, RiskScore.CHRQDATE;
```

Comment: Fantastic!  That was exactly what I needed.

Comment: Glad you got him a working version for his platform!